# Is there a way to randomly auto-click links on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, web, greasemonkey

I'm testing a piece of software that restricts websites by activating a proxy. There seems to be a bug where the proxy just stops working, but only after about an hour or two of surfing the web, or by clicking hundreds, maybe even thousands of links.

Is there an existing solution that can do this? I am also interested in programming a solution if I can solve it that way.

I've heard of greasemonkey plugin for firefox, but I'm not a familiar with javascript. Is there a way that javascript can randomly gather the links on a page and then randomly open one of them?

Comment: Sure. Place `setInterval(function(){ var links=document.getElementsByTagName("a"); links[~~(Math.random()*links.length)].click(); }, 1500)` in the GM script and it should work…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the proxy might have a session timeout of about an hour (absolute) or about an hour of "no activity".

Leaving aside whether it's a good testing methodology, here's **a complete Greasemonkey script** that clicks random links:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// ==/UserScript==

var timeDelaySeconds    = 2;

setInterval (clickRandomLink, timeDelaySeconds * 1000);

function clickRandomLink () {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll ("a");
    /*--- Or fine-tune the links to certain areas or types.  EG:
        var links = document.querySelectorAll ("#content a");
        var links = document.querySelectorAll ("a.comments");
        etc.
    */
    if (links.length) {
        var linkToClick = links[getRandomInt (0, links.length - 1) ];
        var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');

        clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
        linkToClick.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
    }
}

function getRandomInt (min, max) {
    return Math.floor (Math.random () * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
}
```

---

It uses a time-delay to allow for links to AJAX-in. It uses `querySelectorAll()` to allow for fine-tuning which links are used, and it sends an actual click event, as that is the most robust way to trigger the most kinds of links.